# react-jsonschema-form with multiple buttons

Tags: forms, schema, react-jsonschema-forms

I am developing FORM with react-jsonschema-form. Trying to add multiple buttons via schema objects, but unable to add it.

I am able to add inside  tag, but as per my requirement if we want to deal with multiple forms conditionally need to add different buttons for that is there any specific way to add the buttons in schema object.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did

```
<Form schema={this.state.schema}
       onSubmit={this.state.submitForm}
       formData={this.state.content}
       uiSchema={this.state.uiSchema}
       widgets={this.widgets}
       fields={this.fields}>
       <button type="submit" className='btn btn-success>Create a New Post</button>
       <button type="submit" onClick={this.publish} className='btn btn-success'> Publish </button>
</Form>
```

in the publish method

```
publish() {
    this.publishFlag = true
}
```

in the submit method

```
submitForm(formData) {
    if(this.publishFlag) {
    //do something related to publishing
    this.publishFlag = false //unset the flag
    } else {
    //do the default thing
    }

}
```

---

For conditionally showing a button you can do

```
<button type="submit" onClick={this.publish} onSubmit={this.publish}
       className={this.state.buttonState.publishEnabled ? 'btn btn-success' : 'hidden ' }>
                            Publish
                        </button>
```

and in your styles

```
.hidden { display:none; }
```